# Is there a surjective homomorphism from $Z$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

Attempt: $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2 = \{(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)\}$ I tried some examples of a map $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ such that each element in $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is mapped by some element, and checked that it wasn't a homomorphism; so I think it doesn't exist. Is this correct? How do I prove this?

Comment: $D_n/\langle r^2\rangle\simeq \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$, see dihedral groups.

Comment: If there is a surjective homomorphism $f:\mathbf{Z} \to \mathbf{Z}_2 \times \mathbf{Z}_2$, then $\mathbf{Z}/\ker f \cong \mathbf{Z}_2\times \mathbf{Z}_2$. This contradicts something you know about quotients of cyclic groups.